# Can a problem be in NP but not NP-Complete or P?

Tags: complexity-theory, np, np-complete

I am looking at the graphs in:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem

It seems like, there is gap between P and NP-complete. So are there a class of problems that are in NP but neither in P or NP-Complete.

In other words, do the classes P, NP-complete completely cover NP?

And if so, an example is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate, which is linked from the wikipage you added?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/1813 => answer is provided in the link

Answer (score 0):

If P = NP, the answer to your question is that all problems in NP are both in P and in NP-Complete.

If P != NP, the answer to your question is that there are problems known to be in NP, which are known not to be NP-complete but for which no polynomial-time algorithm is yet known. I say there is none yet known because if you knew (1) the problem is in NP and (2) the problem is not in P, well then you'd know P != NP, which we don't.